# Pushing a string with space into an array results in two array elements in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I am trying to push a string element into an array in Perl. The string being pushed contains a space. This is resulting in two elements in the array - split by space.

```
my @filenames;
$filename = "Test Test.test";
push(@filenames, $filename);

while (<@filenames>)
{
        print  "Here: $_\n";
}
```

This gives output as

```
Here: Test

Here: Test.test
```

While I was expecting the output to be:

`enter code here`Here: Test Test.test

How can I achieve the desired output?

Thanks, 
Pranav

Comment: Read the section `I/O Operators` in `man perlop`. You appear to have a misconception about how the `< >` operator works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
my @filenames;
$filename = "Test Test.test";
push(@filenames, $filename);

for (@filenames)
{
    print  "Here: $_\n";
}
```

This produces the expected output.  Not sure why you're doing `<@filenames>`